# Angular UI Router: inherit only URLs (using parent.child states) without nesting views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to inherit states/URLs using `parent.child` notation in UI router. I don't want to inherit views (or nest views inside other views), or inherit controllers, I just want to inherit URLs. I'm using 'ui.router' as a dependency.

This is an example of a router:

```
$stateProvider
.state('products', {
    url: '/products',
    templateUrl: 'view1.html',
    controller: 'products#index'
})

.state('products.show', {
    url: '/:id',        
    templateUrl: 'view2.html',
    controller: 'products#show'
})

.state('products.buy', {
    url: '/:id/:moreParams',
    templateUrl: 'view3.html',
    controller: 'products#buy'
})

.state('products.sell', {
    url: '/:id/:moreParams/:moreParams',
    templateUrl: 'view4.html',
    controller: 'products#sell'
});
```

And the controllers are:

```
angular.module('productsModule', [])

.controller('products#index', function($scope){
})
.controller('products#show', function($scope){
})
.controller('products#buy', function($scope){
})
.controller('products#sell', function($scope){
})
```

Here, all views are completely different, and I don't want to nest any view inside any other view. Also, all controllers are different too, and I don't want to inherit controllers, they are all separate with different functions.

Here's my expected result. What I want to achieve is Angular to allow me to only inherit URLs, so the URLs become:

```
/products
/products/:id
/products/:id/:moreParams
/products/:id/:moreParams/:moreParams
```

(and then have each URL its own view and controller, as specified above)

So far it's not working, and my research is beginning to tell me that this kind of inheritance using `parentState.childState` is only for when you want to have nested views (which is what I don't want. I only want to re-use URLs).

My workaround is to create router URLs like `products_show`, that is, using an underscore instead of a dot, so they are treated as new independent URLs rather than inheritance ones. I'm not sure if this is the best idea, mostly because it looks ugly (though it works perfectly).

Perhaps I should just use `products_show` in case it can't be done with a dot? Ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by moreParams in  /products/:id/:moreParams
/products/:id/:moreParams/:moreParams

Comment: moreParams could be anything, it's just to make an URL different. It could just be url: '/:id/different/URL',

Answer (score 3):

You can have a parent child relationship between the routes without nesting their respective views. You achieve that by specifying an absolute target for your view. Like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('products', {
    url: '/products',
    templateUrl: 'view1.html',
    controller: 'products#index'
})

.state('products.show', {
    url: '/:id',
    views: {'@': {
      templateUrl: 'view2.html',
      controller: 'products#show'
    }}
})

.state('products.buy', {
    url: '/:id/:moreParams',
    views: {'@': {
      templateUrl: 'view3.html',
      controller: 'products#buy'
    }}
})

.state('products.sell', {
    url: '/:id/:moreParams/:moreParams',
    views: {'@': {
      templateUrl: 'view4.html',
      controller: 'products#sell'
    }}
});
```

By doing that you're basically telling ui-router to render your view inside the unnamed `ui-view` in your main index.html, thus, overriding the parent view. Instead of looking for a `ui-view` in the parent view's template.

To understand why this works, you'll have to understand how ui-router decides where to render the view for your route. So, for example, when you do:

```
.state('parent.child', {
    url: '/:id',
    templateUrl: 'child-view.html',
    controller: 'ChildCtrl'
})
```

ui-router will by default translate this to something like:

```
.state('parent.child', {
    url: '/:id',
    views: {'@parent': {
      templateUrl: 'child-view.html',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl'
    }}
})
```

which will cause it to look for an unnamed ui-view inside the parent's view template and render the child view's template inside.
You could also specify more than 1 view for a route, like:

```
.state('parent.child', {
    url: '/:id',
    views: {
      '@parent': {
        templateUrl: 'child-view.html',
        controller: 'ChildCtrl'
      },
      'sidebar@parent': {
        templateUrl: 'child-view-sidebar.html',
        controller: 'ChildViewSidebarCtrl'
      }
    }
})
```

In this case, `child-view.html` will be rendered inside the parent view's unnamed `ui-view` as before. In addition it will also look for a `ui-view="sidebar"` in the parent view's template and render `child-view-sidebar.html` inside.

For more info on this powerful `views` option and how to specify targets for your view, see the [ui-router docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#views)

Answer (score -1):

This is how to write nested states:

```
$stateProvider
.state('products', {
    url: '/products',
    templateUrl: 'view1.html',
    controller: 'products#index'
})

.state('products.show', {
    parent:'products',
    url: '/:id',        
    templateUrl: 'view2.html',
    controller: 'products#show'
})
```